# Converting eslint config from json to JavaScript throws error when exporting config

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am trying to convert my eslint config from json to JavaScript.

After exporting a config object from .eslintrc.js like it sys [in the docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring):

> JavaScript - use .eslintrc.js and export an object containing your configuration.

I get the error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { export default {
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
```

This is the first couple of lines of my config:

```
export default {
    env: {
        browser: true,
```

How can I fix the error?

#### Update

I have named the object and exported the const but get this error:

```
const config = {
    env: {
```

```
export default config;
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
```

Comment: why is it wrapped in a function? `export` token cannot be within a function

Comment: I don't know. I have updated the question.

Comment: If you want to use ES modules with `.js` extension then you have to add `type: "module"` to your `package.json` file. https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

Comment: have you tried with `module.exports = { env: ...... }` ?

Comment: @FelixKling adding this: `],
 "type": "module"
}` at the top level of my `package.json` doesn't solve the issue

Comment: @malarres solved!! Thanks, please add as answer. Would be very useful if they added this to documentation.

Comment: Then I guess eslint loads the config file differently somehow and you have to use CommonJS module syntax instead.

Comment: @Mr.Robot you should use module.exports instead of setting your npm type to module, its way cleaner like that, and also a lot of frameworks that automaticly give you a eslint config (like VueJS) use module.exports

Comment: [*"ESLint does not support ESM configuration at this time"*](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-file-formats-1) - if you use `"type": "module"`, you have to explicitly name your config file `.cjs`, it *still* has to be CommonJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have in my .eslintrc.js :

```
module.exports = {
    env: {
        browser: true,
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use module.exports like this:

```
module.exports = {
  putYour: "config here"
};
```

thats all that you need